# Passing an ArrayList of subclass to a constructor that takes ArrayList of superclass?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Okay so I'm working on this project for the university and I think I'm doing something wrong here, guess I haven't understood java subclassing and class inheritance enough.

I have rewrote my problem in this little form.

```
    class SuperClass {

        int dunno;

        public SuperClass(int dunno) {
            this.dunno = dunno;
        }
    }

    class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        int duncare;

        public SubClass(int dunno, int duncare) {
            super(dunno);
            this.duncare = duncare;
        }
    }

    class VeryBigClass {

        ArrayList<SuperClass> superList;

        public VeryBigClass(ArrayList<SuperClass> superList) {
            this.superList = superList;
        }
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {

        new VeryBigClass(new ArrayList<SubClass>()); // this is the problematic line

    }

}
```

In little words I wrote a lot of classes that extend one more general class, and in many places I have made operations with the superclass (the general one), instead of treating each of the subclasses one by one in the same way.

But I can not create the instance of the class I need, since the constructor takes as argument the superclass. I don't even know how to cast it since `new VeryBigClass(new (ArrayList<SuperClass>)ArrayList<SubClass>());` is obviously wrong. Plus, the construction of these instances will be handled by a json library at some point so I'd rather not do such fancy stuff...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use generics, it should work just fine, is not the same a list of Superclass than a list of Subclass, but the generic solve this:

```
class VeryBigClass<T extends SuperClass> {

    ArrayList<T> superList;

    public VeryBigClass(ArrayList<T> superList) {
        this.superList = superList;
    }
}
```

Comment: But you don't explain why!

Answer (score 5):

The Java Tutorial explains this in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Bottom line, if you have types with an inheritance relationship, like `Sub extends Super` as generics, they do *not* confer an inheritance relationship in the classes that hold them: `Foo<Sub>` is not a subtype of `Foo<Super>`.

The reason is that it would violate the promise of what type the generic type contains, breaking the Liskov Substitution principle. If `List<Sub>` extended `List<Super>`, it would be legal to do this:

```
List<Sub> subs = new ArrayList<Sub>();
List<Super> supers = subs;

Super super = new Super();
supers.add(super);
```

Whoa! Now `subs` has an element of type `Super`, completely illegal!

Because `ArrayList<Sub>` is not a subtype of `List<Super>`, when you invoked

```
new VeryBigClass(new ArrayList<SubClass>());
```

you passed an argument to the constructor that was not legal.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the wildcard `? extends super` That is, any class that extends super.

**Example**:

```
class VeryBigClass {

    ArrayList<? extends SuperClass> superList;

    public VeryBigClass(ArrayList<? extends SuperClass> superList) {
        this.superList = superList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wildcards for declared types get a little dicey. They are good for method arguments and return types, because those feed types with better declarations, but as a variable type they provide too little information. It's better to follow the advice given earlier to make `VeryBig` a generic class.

Comment: Oh, didn't know one could do this! It will be helpful for sure, thanks :)